# Cannot access value in JavaScript Array - Elements appear to be structured in a weird way

Tags: javascript

I have an array which looks like this after I `console.log` it:

```
[
  {
    Country: 'US',
    CityName: 'Seattle',
    Region: 'WA',
    PostalCode: '99301',
    StreetName: '3512 Alaska Street'
  },
  to_EmailAddress: { results: [ [Object] ] }
]
```

Funny thing is, the length of this array is 1, not 2. So, when I try `console.log(arr[0])`, I get:

```
{
  Country: 'US',
  CityName: 'Seattle',
  Region: 'WA',
  PostalCode: '99301',
  StreetName: '3512 Alaska Street'
}
```

When I try to `console.log(arr[1])` I get `undefined`.

How do I get the `to_EmailAddress` attribute? Even better, how do I make `to_EmailAddress: { results: [ [object] ] }` part of the 1st element in the array. Basically, I want:

```
[
  {
    Country: 'US',
    CityName: 'Seattle',
    Region: 'WA',
    PostalCode: '99301',
    StreetName: '3512 Alaska Street',
    to_EmailAddress: { results: [ [Object] ] }
  },
]
```

But I am not sure how to create that when I cannot even access `to_EmailAddress` attribute

Comment: `which looks like this` how? that's not valid is it? How can you console.log something like that

Comment: Have you tried `arr.to_EmailAddress` ? It looks like an array to which a property was added. That may not be very common, but doing so is valid and allowed.

Comment: @JaromandaX I was referring when I try to console log the element, but Peter seems to be right, it added a property to an array. Any way that I can merge that property into the object which is specified as the element of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a monkey patched property `to_EmailAddress`.

```js
const arr = [{
    Country: 'US',
    CityName: 'Seattle',
    Region: 'WA',
    PostalCode: '99301',
    StreetName: '3512 Alaska Street'
}];

arr.to_EmailAddress = { 
    results: []
}


console.log(arr);
```

Gives the output:

```
[
  {
    Country: 'US',
    CityName: 'Seattle',
    Region: 'WA',
    PostalCode: '99301',
    StreetName: '3512 Alaska Street'
  },
  to_EmailAddress: { results: [] }
]
```

Just acces it like any other property:

```js
console.log(arr.to_EmailAddress);
```

Comment: cool, it did not even come to my mind such abomination can be used :D, but it makes sense

Comment: @libik In JS arrays just objects too. And like any other object, you can add properties ;) Have done this accidentally by myself with `Object.assign()` while playing around.

Comment: Hmmm .. is there a way to move the propery to the object which is part of the array?

Comment: I would fix the origin of this issue. How was this array created?

Comment: Well, it is a bit complicated. Originally I had a NESTED JSON structure (object) which I flattened and then for each (leaf) field I generated the data. After doing so, I tried to RETURN back the original structure of the object, but it seems that I failed.

The way I was able to return to the original structure is by remembering the path to each node of the object.